# how to solve InvalidXml-The provided content must be of XML content type error while decoding x12 in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I created logic app with following components,

1. http trigger
2. decode `x12` message
3. transform xml
4. Response (output of transform xml)
   when i trigger the flow, After decoding x12 message while transforming xml it throws error like

   > InvalidXml-The provided content must be of XML content type.

i gave input for transform xml as "`@{base64ToString(item()?['Payload'])}`" and in for each i gave input as badmessage.
And my screenshot looks like this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NnaU.png)

how to get xml from transformation xml component of logic app.Please fix the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need after the decode, do a for each by "GoodMessages":

```
"foreach": "@body('Decode_EDIFACT_message')?['GoodMessages']"
```

And then convert to String, the base64 item payload as input of the transform:

```
"Transform_XML": {
   "inputs": {
      "content": "@base64ToString(items('For_each')?['Payload'])",
      "integrationAccount": {
         "map": {
            "name": "EfactD95BCoarri_To_InternalCoarri"
         }
      }
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "Xslt"
}
```